# Can I count {(Sum non-NULL value in the past time)/ # of non-NULL }?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have table like the following,

```
ID | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 
----------------------------------------------
1  |  0   |   0  |  90  |  90  |  100 |  100 |
2  | NULL | 130  | 100  |  70  |   0  |   0  |
```

I need to calculate the mean of historical record into a new table.

For example, for ID#1 in year 2009, I want to calculate 0/1=0 and insert into [2009] in the new table, in year 2010, I want to calculate (0+0)/2=0 and insert into [2010] in the new table. For year 2011, I want to calculate (0+0+90)/3 = 30 and insert into [2011] in the new table and so on and so forth.

For ID#2, since the value in [2009] is 'NULL', I have to ignore the value. Hence, I wanna keep 'NULL' in [2009] in the new table and calculate (130)/1 = 130 in [2010] in the new table. For year 2011, I want to calculate (130+100)/2 = 115 and insert into [2011] in the new table. Is there a way that could (Sum non-NULL value in the past time)/ # of non-NULL ?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Can you add the expected result in table format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help

```
CREATE temporary TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mean_temp AS 
  (SELECT * 
   FROM   (SELECT id, 2009 AS years, [2009] AS valu 
           FROM   yourtable 
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT id, 2010, [2010] 
           FROM   yourtable 
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT id, 2011, [2011] 
           FROM   yourtable 
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT id, 2012, [2012] 
           FROM   yourtable 
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT id, 2013, [2013] 
           FROM   yourtable 
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT id, 2014, [2014] 
           FROM   yourtable)A) 

SELECT id,years, 
       (SELECT Sum(valu) 
        FROM   mean_temp b 
        WHERE  a.id = b.id 
               AND a.years >= b.years) / (SELECT Count(valu) 
                                          FROM   mean_temp c 
                                          WHERE  a.id = c.id 
                                                 AND a.years >= c.years) 
FROM   mean_temp a 
ORDER  BY id, 
          years
```

`Count` aggregate will not count `NULL` values so for division only `not null` values will be counted